# Memory usage in empty application

Tags: android

I have created an empty application on Android 4.0.3 and when I dump heap with hprof, I see that 8,3 MB are used by the application (on my Nexus S)!

It is very big for an empty application. When I analyze the memory usage, I see that the main part (5,6 MB) is used by android.content.res.Resources class. I don't understand why it takes so much memory, there is just the small default icon (4 kB) and the default layout and string files (1 kB each). Is it normal ? have you the same result on other Android version ? Somebody has an idea to reduce it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on ICS (I assume you are), then it's because of hardware acceleration.
Not sure if it's enabled by default (I don't think it is), I don't have any ICS :(

> Hardware accelerated drawing is not all full of win. For example on
>   the PVR drivers of devices like the Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus, simply
>   starting to use OpenGL in a process eats about 8MB of RAM. Given that
>   our process overhead is about 2MB, this is pretty huge. That RAM takes
>   away from other things, such as the number of background processes
>   that can be kept running, potentially slowing down things like app
>   switching.

Source: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/2FXDCz8x93s

Edit: To reduce it you'll need to set your build target to honeycomb or lower, but then you can't use hardware acceleration either. Your call.

Comment: Yes, I am on ICS ! Thanks a lot, I didn't know that ! I will check as soon as possible your suggestion.

Comment: It was not that. I try to use Android 2.2 build target and it still use 8MB (on my Nexus S). In the test app manifest file, I also set :

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

-> minSdk : Android 2.2
-> targetSdk : Android 2.3.3

On an emulator with Android 4.0.3, it uses 5.8MB and on an emulator with Android 2.2, it uses 1.7MB.