# Android: how much ram should an empty app take up when running?

Tags: android, memory, ram

I've created a new application with just an empty activity that does absolutely nothing and I'm seeing a memory usage of 16mb in android studio. Does this make sense? Is this the "weight" of an empty activity before anything else is added?

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.someproject.testproject">

<application android:allowBackup="true"     android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

and.. thats it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625826/memory-usage-in-empty-application

Comment: @davidgiga1993 - yeah, I saw that previous question. I've tried lowering the apps version to api 14 but see no improvement in memory. Even if it would work, it seems strange that the only way to achieve less ram would be to run on <14 - since just about no-one runs those versions anymore anyway.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that it could be a realistic number. Take a look at the allocations to see what takes that much. Also just for comparison use the adb shell dumpsys meminfo command and compate it to the values shown in android studio